# Salesforce Omnistudio - Omniscript requires refresh everytime

Tags: salesforce

I am new to vlocity. Me and my colleagues are facing a wierd issue when using omniscript. We have to refresh the page again and again in order to select any other component on omniscript.  We tried creating new orgs but no luck. Can you please help on this issue!

Tried creating multiple orgs but no luck

Answer (score 0):

I am reading this as you have a Omniscript page (a Step) and you retrieve or get some data, and then display it for further input or selection.

The Step really only processes once.  Changing the data does not cause the step to refresh.  Refreshing the browser however forces the page to reload.

This behaviour is that Omniscript updates the JSON values when it first processes and display.  It does not refresh based on input within that step a second or subsequent time.  It will update the data JSON however when moving to the next step.  That means you need to capture data, move to the next page (Step) and then if you want to change your selection, you can use the Previous button to return and reprocess the step with new options.

Alternatively you can use a setvalues action, which will appear as a button when in a Step.

I am basing my answer based on what you have described and am assuming you are trying to do.  Without more detail it is difficult to advise you further.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if at all this helps you:

1. Is your debug mode enabled? this slows your org
2. OmniStudio also slows your org
3. Is any debugger enabled in any of your tabs?
4. Make space in your org, delete unnecessary components and release memory.